# Form Plugin for Craft CMS

Tags: templating, form

I'm looking for a plugin like ContactForm from P&T but with more options like validation for custom fields or the possibility to build a own mail template for the mail at his self.

I want to handle all with the same plugin if this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can find most plugins for Craft here: https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins

There's a few different form plugins to choose from, not sure if all of them will have what you're looking for.

I've used [Sprout Forms](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms) a few times and you should be able to do both of what you're asking for.

Comment: I've have searched there for a form plugin. A lot of them are "Form Builders", i'm looking for something like basic ContactForm from P&T but with more options.

For exemple: By using ContactForm I must name my fields: message[Firma], message[Fname] etc...

But this names are not valid in js, so i can't validate the fields with a script.